# get_posts from a category id doesn't work

Tags: posts

I use the following code to get portfolio type posts from category id, but it doesn't work.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $items, 'post_type'=>'portfolio','orderby' => 'date','order'=>'DESC','category' => 5 );
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $return_html='......';
}
```

however,if I leave the category id empty, it' fine and will show all categories posts. I'm sure that there are many posts under category 5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you `register_taxonomy_for_post_type()` or otherwise enable support for the `category` taxonomy for the `portfolio` post type?

Comment: Yes,I did that.

Answer (score 2):

It's

```
'post_date'
```

not

```
'date'
```

so

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => $items, 'post_type'=>'portfolio','orderby' => 'post_date','order'=>'DESC','category' => 5 );
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach($posts as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    $return_html='......';
}
```

Should fix you up.

Comment: Thanks,I have corrected but it still doesn't work.